# Need help debugging - IE not displaying jquery background slider on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, web-testing

I've had this problem for over a month and client isn't paying me until it's fixed.

The website is: http://www.cardwells.co.nz

I'm using WordPress as the CMS with a template and some custom work.

The template comes with a slider background inbuilt which works in all browsers except IE.

I'm also using http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html for the scroller at the bottom.

Basically I have no clue WHY it's not working in IE - everything seems like it should be working. I've run the site through w3 checker and used that IE specific CSS files - but no dice.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure but it might possibly be a conflict between the slider at the bottom and the background slider. I'll remove the bottom one and see.

Comment: What's the earliest you need support for?  IE6/IE7/IE8/IE9?

Comment: Also, where did you test it?  It works on IE7 and IE8 for me.  On IE6 I get a bunch of errors so I recommend putting ```window.onerror = function() { return true; }``` before all other JS.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Seems I got it sorted by disabling and reenabling the theme I'm using. Odd that, maybe a file was missed or a DB connection error. So weird.

Comment: would you please add an answer (when you can), just to mark the question as solved (good house keeping, etc)?

Comment: There was no real solution - really =\ I disabled, removed, reuploaded and reenabled the template. Either a file was a miss or a DB connection error somewhere along the line. So stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no real solution - really =\ I disabled, removed, reuploaded and reenabled the template. Either a file was a miss or a DB connection error somewhere along the line. So stupid.